# Spritesheet animations are vertical not horizontal

Tags: animation, sprite, game-engine, godot, sprite-sheet

I have a sprite sheet that I want to animate in Godot game engine but I bugs because Godot makes the frames cycle right to left when my sprite sheet has animations going from top to bottom. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to use `AnimatedSprite`, or doing particle effects, or something else? Please clarify. I'm guessing it is `AnimatedSprite` given the contents of the linked image, but ern... Yeah you can do the animation however you want. Perhaps you want to use `AnimatedTexture`?

Answer (score 0):

you can change the settings from editor

[image]

Here i have set the Hframes to 4 byt you need to set the vframes to the vertical frames number from your spritesheet. In the same way you need to set and your hframes